# Fade pixelate (blurred) image to normal after mouse over using jQuery

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have an pixelate (blurred) background and normal image.

How to return the image to normal after the user hold the mouse over it a few times?
Jquery.

Sample:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JpaT.jpg]

Comment: I don't think jQuery has the ability to animate one image into another, if that's what you are asking.  You would have to use some library that had an API to blur the image and unblur it on mouseover, or use some CSS tricks like this:  http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur

Comment: Can you link to a jsfiddle or code that you've written? Please don't expect others to write your code for you..

Comment: Just swap out blurred vs clear images using jQueries element.hover() method.

Comment: Hmmm...Just a guess but do you want to start with the blurred image and have the user "scratch-off" the image revealing the clear image?  Anyway...@user2605575 we need more explanation from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question it is a bit unclear what you try to achieve, but assuming you mean how to earse/paint in one image into the other can simply use the following steps:

- Set the destination image (normal in this case) as background image to the canvas.
- Draw in the blurred version in the canvas - this will cover the destination image
- Change composite mode to `destination-out` which will erase what you draw.

You will of course have to implement the logic for mouse and drawing.

Here is on example with **[live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/mjryh/)**.

The initial code can be:

```
var ctx = $('#demo')[0].getContext('2d'), /// get context
    img = new Image,                      /// load a new image
    isDown = false,                       /// for mouse button
    radius = 15;                          /// eraser radius

/// setup logic

$(img).on('load', function() {            /// onload for image

    /// when image has been loaded, attach event listeners for mouse
    $('#demo').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        isDown = true;
        erase(getXY(e));
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (isDown) erase(getXY(e));
    })
    .on('mouseup', function(e) {
        isDown = false;
    });

    /// draw blurred image        
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    /// change composite mode so we can erase
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
});
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/mi3zfEX.jpg'; /// blurred image
```

The destination background (normal) for the canvas is defined with CSS:

```
#demo {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/v85BQ8k.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    cursor:crosshair;
}
```

Then we only need to draw something at mouse position to earse the overlay and reveal the background:

```
function erase(pos) {
    ctx.beginPath();                               /// start new path
    ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI); /// draw a circle
    ctx.closePath();                               /// close path
    ctx.fill();                                    /// fill it
}
```

We can fill it with any color - it doesn't matter cause it will erase in the area where it's drawn anyways as we use `destination-out` mode for composite mode.

The only last thing we need to do is to adjust the mouse position so we draw relative to canvas - this function returns an object with `x` and `y` properties:

```
function getXY(e) {
    var r = $('#demo')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return {x: e.clientX - r.left, y: e.clientY - r.top};
}
```